# How to implement a filtering feature with NSCoding as a database solution?

Tags: ios, database, filter, nscoding

I have an app which lets a user create and save categories (e.g. 'Feeling Happy/Sad') **and** a user can create, save Mood Notes by providing title, category, and the text/note.

I used `NSCoding` as a database solution, but I dont know all the details about `NSCoding`.

**So I'm required to provide a feature where a user can tap on a category cell and see all the notes that have *that* category.**

I dont know how to implement this feature using `NSCoding`, how to implement sorting/filtering, what to do if a user created categories that are identical, etc.

Also, going though some iOS tutorial, it said that

> `NSCoding` doesn't support querying or creating complex object graphs

What does this line mean (not literally)? What can I do about implementing the requested feature?

Thank you!

Comment: NSCoding itself is not a database solution, but a protocol which can encode/decode classes/structs. The encoded representation can be saved to a store. (File system/Database like CoreData). The encoded representation of the data can not be sorted/queried because you can think of it as a big data blob. CoreData for example can only sort types like integer values or string values.
So if you want to use specific queries in your database, you could look into core data and Managed Object Models. (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for helping clarify that! Please, may I ask, how bad this idea is if I'm gonna filter them/objects through basic `for-loop` and `if-else` when the data is decoded to objects?

Comment: It really depends on the amount of the data and how often you sort your datastructure. If there are only like 50 structs in an array, it'll work fine. I'd suggest implementing Comparable protocol (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable) on your data struct, then you can call .sort on your array of items. And if you hit performance problems due to a lot more items, you can still migrate to a database solution.